# Database of unsolved problems in mathematics

Tags: soft-question

Is there a good database of unsolved problems in mathematics?

Comment: yes, here. http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered yours is one of them currently.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics, but I wouldn't call it a good database, in fact, the article has multiple issues.

Comment: This is one of may sources: http://unsolveddatabase.org/about

Comment: Digga, dein Ernst? There are only TWO problems ... ROFL

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are plenty. Here are some from my bookmarks that I could find easily.

http://www.openproblemgarden.org

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics

Comment: Both of these sites are not good. Openproblemgarden is not complete in the sense that there are important open problems that the list does not contain. The second is interesting but I am searching for a more comprehensive site. However, thanks ;-D

Comment: Well if you know of those 'important' open problems already, why would you need a resource with those on it?

Comment: I don't really know those important problems. But I know that there are some of them that aren't in the list. I feel it.

Answer (score 1):

The site called scilag (https://www.scilag.net/) is another more recent one too.

"SciLag is a free web-based platform for facilitating dynamic organisation of scientific problems at a research level. It represents an online service for scientists for sharing their knowledge about the forefront of research. The current version is set up for the Mathematical community only to test and refine the concept in action."